# Blocking spam requests on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, spam-prevention

I am currently receiving lots of spam hits which are captured by my apache server and responded 404, e.g.

```
23.19.31.54 - - [06/Nov/2012:11:54:28 +0000] "GET http://ad.adserverplus.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=728x90&section=2687744&pub_url=${PUB_URL} HTTP/1.0" 404 1367 "http://wealthterritory.com/index.php?view=article&catid=41%3Aservices&id=4812%3A2011-07-06-13-26-55&format=pdf&option=com_content&Itemid=97" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
```

However this is resulting in lot of bandwidth usage. I am wondering if I can allow requests for only particular domains for e.g. if request comes for abcd.com then only allow the request.

P.S: I also tried blocking the IPs in iptables but it doesn't work since requests start coming from other IPs.

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered, and I found the solution long back (forgot to answer here), I would post the solution as well. The solution was to switch off the proxy for everyone else and allow access only to the site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName deny.all
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myserver.com
    ServerAlias www.myserver.com myserver.com ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
   </Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

This resulted in 403 to all the spam requests, which is shown as follows in apache logs -

```
173.208.94.246 - - [07/Nov/2012:11:47:47 +0000] "GET http://ad.scanmedios.com/st?ad_type=iframe&ad_size=300x250&section=3522632 HTTP/1.0" 403 287 "http://piecehealth.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5935:2012-01-07-16-34-29&catid=40:health-fitness&Itemid=96" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/10.04 Chromium/14.0.804.0 Chrome/14.0.804.0 Safari/535.1"
```